# Algebraic Proof of Sum of Exponential Powers is Product of Exponentials

Tags: taylor-expansion, exponentiation

Can somebody provide a proof of the summation of powers law for the product of two exponentials, using only algebra and the Taylor series, no derivatives or calculus tricks?

Comment: You mean proving the functional equation $f(x)f(y) = f(x+y)$?

Comment: ... but the derivative tricks are much more fun

Comment: ^ Yes and yes. I suppose it's not that bad, I thought it was worse.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\exp{(a+b)}&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(a+b)^n}{n!}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\frac{a^kb^{n-k}}{n!}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{a^kb^{n-k}}{k!(n-k)!}\\
&=\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{a^k}{k!}\right)\cdot\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{b^n}{n!}\right)\\
&=\exp{(a)}\cdot\exp{(b)}.~~\blacksquare
\end{align}$$

The key steps of the derivation are the [Binomial Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) and the [Cauchy product formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product).